# Testing Meteor Facebook login with Cucumber

Tags: meteor, cucumber, facebook-login, meteor-velocity

I have the following template code

login.html

```
<button id="facebook-login" class="button button-block button-positive">
  Login with Facebook
</button>
```

login.js

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #facebook-login': function () {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook();
  }
});
```

How can I test the positive and negative paths with xolvio:cucumber?

Comment: Currently there is not a fake/stub for Facebook. There are fake implementations for Twitter and GitHub. You would need to either copy one of those fakes, or wait until I get around to writing a Facebook stub :) See these links | https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-twitter-stub | https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-github-stub |

Comment: I'll update a proper answer when I actually write the Facebook fake, unless someone else writes it first

Comment: could you please take a look at the following question? thank you!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427249/xolvio-cucumber-getting-errors-in-console-yet-all-tests-are-passing

Answer (score 0):

There is now a facebook-fake package which can be found here: https://atmospherejs.com/dropz/facebook-fake

After installing it you'll find that you don't have to have your test code enter a username/password in the window that the real facebook auth packages opens up instead the logins should always work (due to being faked out).