# Xolvio Cucumber - Getting errors in console yet all tests are passing

Tags: meteor, cucumber, webdriver-io, meteor-velocity

I have the following code. It seems like my tests pass, but I get tons of errors in my console. What's going on? Are my tests non-deterministic and being re-run? If so how do I prevent the errors?

login.feature:

```
Feature: User authentication

  As a user
  I want to be able to login
  So that I can have all the good stuff that comes with user accounts

  Background:
    Given I am signed out

  Scenario: A user can sign up with valid information
    Given I am on the home page
    When I open the sign up modal
    And I enter my desired authentication information
    Then I should be logged in
```

step_definitions.js

```
this.When(/^I open the sign up modal$/, function (callback) {
      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
      helper.world.browser.
        click('[data-ion-modal="signup"]').
        waitForVisible('.#signup-form', 2000).
        call(callback);
    });

    this.When(/^I enter my desired authentication information$/, function (callback) {
      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
      helper.world.browser.
        waitForExist('#signup-form', 2000).
        waitForVisible('#signup-form').
        setValue('#signup-email', 'newuser@test.com').
        setValue('#signup-password', 'password').
        submitForm('#signup-form').
        call(callback);
    });

    this.Then(/^I should be logged in$/, function (callback) {
      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
      helper.world.browser.
        waitForExist('.tabs', 2000).
        waitForVisible('.tabs').
        call(callback);
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a meteor-cucumber regression. I'm in the process of rewriting cucumber, expect this problem to go away in the next release.